# java.io.NotSerializableException for unknown classes

Tags: java, serialization, serializable, notserializableexception

I'm trying to make my classes Serializable. All of my classes are, but still it throws me NotSerializableException for some other classes that I can't find it's usages (e.g. com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle, WClipboard).

What can I do and how can I bypass these classes when serializing or make them Serializable?

***SOLVED***

The problem was in LookAndFeel I have used in my JFrames and JDialogs (problem with `XPStyle`). Second one (`WClipboard`), it was used by third party class I got from here. This class uses Clipboard.

I made Clipboard field `transient` and LookAndFeel I couldn't manage, just by deleting it.

Comment: In general, classes associated with the UI (like XPStyle and WClipboard) are intentionally made not serializable because they can interface with OS specific (ie native) objects that cannot be serialized.

Comment: This often arises when you use inner classes that.are serializable and that are nested inside classes that  extend Swing components. The inner class serializes the outer class along with itself, even if that wasn't your intent. Solution: static.

Comment: Please, take a look at my comment in next answer. I know the reason but don't know solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the data to be serialized for persistence or transfer, than you can declare those `transient`

However, if you need the data in those Objects (classes) to be persisted, transported via TCP / UDP, etc. than you might want to `extend` the class, and implement your own interpretation of it, so that you can then declare your extended class `Serializable`.

---

A final option might be to use a different method of `Serialization`, such as those provided by **FST**, **Kryo**, etc. Often times these Serialization libraries can use `Reflection` to Serialize Objects that the default Java implementation cannot.

Comment: I don't know who uses this clases at all. I I knew it, I would do advised things, but how to make it transient or extend it when I have never imported (even directly) any of these classes?

Comment: Going off what you have posted, `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle` is a style, and you're more than likely applying the style at Startup for your Swing JFrame in the init() or main class. Your best option is to find and identify where this style is being set, and ensure that you're not creating an Object before setting the style. If you're creating an object, than you need to mark it transient. Otherwise, what has been said earlier is probably your best option: make it static.